# Why do I get no such table error when installing Apache Airflow on Mac?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pip, airflow

It was so hard to put that right title. Ok, here it goes. I was following this tutorial to install Apache Airflow on my Mac (Mojave version) -

https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-apache-airflow-df1aa77d7b1b

Right at the first step after performing the pip install airflow task, when I run the airflow version command I am getting the following error and then the airflow version appears -

> ERROR - Failed on pre-execution callback using  Traceback (most recent call last): 
>   File
>   "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1244, in _execute_context
>       cursor, statement, parameters, context   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 552, in do_execute
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: log

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli_action_loggers.py",
>   line 68, in on_pre_execution
>       cb(**kwargs)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli_action_loggers.py",
>   line 99, in default_action_log
>       session.add(log)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 119, in
>   **exit**
>       next(self.gen)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py",
>   line 45, in create_session
>       session.commit()   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 1026, in commit
>       self.transaction.commit()   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 493, in commit
>       self._prepare_impl()   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 472, in _prepare_impl
>       self.session.flush()   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2451, in flush
>       self._flush(objects)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2589, in _flush
>       transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 68, in **exit**
>       compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 129, in reraise
>       raise value   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2549, in _flush
>       flush_context.execute()   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py",
>   line 422, in execute
>       rec.execute(self)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py",
>   line 589, in execute
>       uow,   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py",
>   line 245, in save_obj
>       insert,   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py",
>   line 1120, in _emit_insert_statements
>       statement, params   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 988, in execute
>       return meth(self, multiparams, params)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
>   line 287, in _execute_on_connection
>       return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)   File
>   "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
>       distilled_params,   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1248, in _execute_context
>       e, statement, parameters, cursor, context   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
>       util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 383, in raise_from_cause
>       reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 128, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1244, in _execute_context
>       cursor, statement, parameters, context   File "/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 552, in do_execute
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
>   table: log [SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event,
>   execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
>   [parameters: ('2019-08-12 20:50:24.960006', None, None, 'cli_version',
>   None, 'karthikv', '{"host_name": "192-168-1-6.tpgi.com.au",
>   "full_command": "[\'/Users/karthikv/anaconda3/bin/airflow\',
>   \'version\']"}')]

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Can someone help me what this error means and how to solve it? I understand from the instructions that by default SQLLite db gets installed and a single DAG restrictions would be in place before we get into setting up backend database say PostgreSQL.

I tried to uninstall using pip uninstall airflow to perform clean installation again. I get the following error -

> WARNING: Skipping airflow as it is not installed.

Kindly help me in solving the issue (or) pointing me to resources where I can do further reading.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to perform initialization after installation:

```bash
$ export AIRFLOW_HOME=some/dir
$ airflow db init  # or `airflow initdb` for the legacy 1.X
```

If `AIRFLOW_HOME` is unset, `~/airflow/` will be created and used. This is where the config and logs will be stored; if you want to reset the configuration, remove the dir stored in `AIRFLOW_HOME` and rerun `airflow db init`.

Now other commands should work, e.g.

```bash
$ airflow db check
[2021-02-06 23:35:21,577] {db.py:756} INFO - Connection successful.
```

Source: [Initializing Airflow Database](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation.html#initializing-airflow-database) section from `airflow` docs. Kudos to [Anas Tiour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4017403/anas-tiour) who notified about the command line interface change in 2.0.0 in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515434/why-do-i-get-no-such-table-error-when-installing-apache-airflow-on-mac/57515985?noredirect=1#comment116833315_57515985)!

Comment: Thanks @hoefling. Worked like a charm! I am surprised that link didn't specify this mandatory step

Comment: Glad I could help! I guess the tutorial you mentioned isn't very thoroughly written; best is to check out the official docs when you're stuck. E.g. the [Installation](https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html) section mentions the `initdb` invocation.

Comment: Apparently Apache Airflow CLI has been changed. I am on version 2.0.0, and the command is: `airflow db init`

Comment: @AnasTiour very nice comment, thanks! Updated the answer to cover the cli change.